# Why does NuGet pack ignores content files?

Tags: nuget, nuspec

When trying to add arbitrary content files to a NuGet package, the files - specified via `<files>` element - are ignored completely. They aren't event picked up into the `nupkg` archive.

`<files>` section in `nuspec` file:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin/Release/de-DE/*.resources.dll" target="contentFiles/any/any/de-DE" />
</files>
```

There are two files in this directory:

- ApplicationName.resources.dll
- LibraryName.resources.dll

But none of them are included into the `nupkg`.

The `<files>` section is built like the Microsoft documentation suggests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft documentation seems to be wrong. While wildcards are allowed in the `<contentFiles>` section, they seem to not work in the `<files>` section.

Change the `<file>` specifications to explicit paths without wildcards, so that you have one per file in the end:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin/Release/de-DE/ApplicationName.resources.dll" target="contentFiles/any/any/de-DE" />
    <file src="bin/Release/de-DE/LibraryName.resources.dll" target="contentFiles/any/any/de-DE" />
</files>
```